# Two components listening to the same observable

Tags: angular

I have two (main,sub) components and a service. All on the same module

In my service I have this code:

```
private showThisSource = new BehaviorSubject<({ show: boolean })>({} as any);
currentThis = this.showThisSource.asObservable();

changeThis(data: { show: boolean }) {
      this.showThisSource.next(data);
}
```

In my main component I have this code:

```
showThis(){
  this.theServiceAbove.changeThis({show:true})
}
```

In my other component (sub) I have this code:

```
currentThis$ = this.theServiceAbove.currentThis
   .pipe(
         tap(data=>
              console.log('Display to log')
            ) 
        );

vm$ = combineLatest(
   this.currentThis$
  ).pipe(
         map(([currentThis]) =>
           ({ currentThis}))
        )

--template---

<div>
   <ng-container *ngIf="(vm$ | async) as vm">
   <ng-container>
</div>
```

Now the problem is, even I called the changeThis on main component the currentThis$ of sub component is not occurring, how do I know that? Because the `console.log('Display to log');` does not appear.
I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I think it might be an import issue. Are you importing `combineLatest` from `rxjs` or `rxjs/operators`? If it's the latest than that's your issue. Can you post your imports?

Comment: Are you planning on using more than one subject or observable with vm$?

Comment: @tuckerjt07 yes, I just displayed 1. Other observables are almost the same of that.

Comment: @ionut-t  `import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: I've put your code in a stackblitz that I forked from one that I've use it for another answer and is working. Press the Show This button and change the route. ignore the rest of the code there. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zs6tld

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in your code. I put it into a Stackblitz and made the necessary changes and got the console.log to display as well as put something into the view.

```
.pipe(
   tap(data=>
       console.log('Display to log') // Removed semi-colon from this line
   ) 
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynvtao

Comment: sorry, that's my typo error. but that's not the solution.